# How can I add individual users to a Query-Based Distribution List?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2003

I have query-based distribution lists setup for all of the offices in my company. I need to add the HR distro to each of these query-based distribution groups, however since they don't have the same office location, they don't show up in the query results.

Is there a way to add an individual user/distro group to a query-based distribution group?

The way around it that I see is to create a new HR distro group for each office (i.e. HR-CityName) with that office included...however, I'm looking for a better solution if possible.

Thanks in advance.

I'm using Windows Server 2003 and Exchange 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC you can't add individual users or groups to a query-based DL. The whole point of it is that the results are purely based on a filter/pattern.

You need to either figure out how to make the HR group match that pattern (unlikely if its all about physical office location of the users) or create a "public" DL that the users see, and have that include the Query based DL plus the other one that you are trying to add.